# How to Batch multiple Web Addresses within One Firefox Window from application Launch

Tags: batch-file, firefox

Here is what I'm trying to do,

I want to be able to double click on a Batch File and open all the the web addresses contained within. Even if the program is not running I need all the Tabs in one window. Currently, If Firefox is closed, some sort of randomness occurs where sometimes it's opened all in one window while other times the tabs are split unevenly over multiple windows and most commonly they are all opened in their own window. Here's what I've been using..

```
@echo off
start https://youtube.com
start https://www.twitch.tv/directory
start https://stackoverflow.com
start https://instagram.com
start https://google.com
start https://calendar.google.com
start https://drive.google.com
```

How can I force this to only open in multiple tabs within one window rather then multiple windows. This doesn't seem to happen if already have an instance of Firefox open. I tried adding,

```
start Firefox
```

at the beginning, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any and all tips and pointers.

Comment: What about a slight delay before each `start` line, like `timeout 1`? Or, when you put `start Firefox` first, place one delay, say `timeout 3`, after it?

Comment: There is also a [`-new-tab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) option, like `[start] firefox.exe -new-tab URL`...

Answer (score 0):

This seamed to work.

```
@echo off
start firefox

timeout 2

start firefox -new-tab "https://youtube.com"
start firefox -new-tab "https://www.twitch.tv/directory"
start firefox -new-tab "https://stackoverflow.com"
start firefox -new-tab "https://instagram.com"
```

Thanks @aschipfl for your pointer